# asp.net httphandler recursion

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

I'm using the RssToolkit for .net. I'm using an Httphandler to return rss feeds. The feedID is passed in as a querystring parameter. If no parameter is passed in, I would like to have the the handler return a feed that is an aggreate of some of the feeds that the handler can handle. What I'm wondering is, can the handler recurse? Can it call itself with a querystring parameter several times and retrieve several feeds and then return the compiled result. Or is the httpHandler unable to recurse in this manner?

for exampele

if you went to
rss.ashx
it would call rss.ashx?c=feed1 and rss.ashx?c=feed2
each of these would return an RSS feed and it would compile them into an aggregate and return it as rss.ashx.

Comment: I agree with @DustinDavis, why do this? why not have your handler determine if it has a querystring then get that feed if not the aggregate all feeds? Why add the overhead of multiple calls? If you're already in the handler then why go back out just to call itself? I think you want to just make multiple calls to your GetFeed() method from within your handler if no querystring was given then return the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will (in a sense) if you're making a new call to the web server but that's not really recursion. but why do that? Just have your handler determine what it needs to do and then do it. If querystring == null then c=... If not that then do a redirect instead

Comment: Actually, I took your advice and abstracted how I build my feeds a little and then put it all together in the else case (so I built the feed rather than called it). I'm still curious though, if the handler can call itself, but it's no longer an issue. When I was doing it, it would not return any of the 'recursed' results.